# Mocking Vue Plugin functionality with a custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I currently and trying to implement my own simple confirm dialogue into my Vue app. However, a lot of the popular packages allow you to use this sort of usage.

```js
this.$dialog.confirm('Please confirm to continue').then(function(dialog) {
    console.log('Clicked on proceed');
  }).catch(function() {
    console.log('Clicked on cancel');
});
```

I basically want to be able to fire off my custom confirm dialog component all across my app programatically... and then do something else depending on whether a user clicked Confirm or Cancel, just like the above example.

Is there a best practice for setting this up? I can't figure the best way to get access to the component with `this.$myComponent`.

Is making my own custom plugin what I want to do here, or are there more straightforward ways to accomplish this?